# sed: Substituting text pattern containing backslash

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have an issue with `sed` that I have been able to recreate with the following simple example.

Consider the following input file (**input.txt**):

```
C:\A\quick\brown\fox\ jumps over the lazy dog
C:\A\quick\brown\fox\ ran with the hounds
```

I want to generate the following output

```
C:\Animal\ jumps over the lazy dog
C:\Animal\ ran with the hounds
```

I tried to create a simple shell script, using sed, but it is not performing the required substitution.    Here is my script:

```
FROM_PATTERN="C:\A\quick\brown\fox\"
TO_PATTERN="C:\Animal\"

#FROM_PATTERN="C:\\A\\quick\\brown\\fox\\"       # Escaping backslash does not help either
#TO_PATTERN="C:\\Animal\\"       # Escaping backslash does not help either


sed 's/$FROM_PATTERN/$TO_PATTERN/g' input.txt
#sed 's/"$FROM_PATTERN"/"$TO_PATTERN"/g' input.txt       # Quoting the pattern does not help either
```

---

I am running `bash` version `GNU bash, version 4.4.12(3)-release-(x86_64-unknown-cygwin)`

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed and bash):

```
FROM_PATTERN='C:\A\quick\brown\fox\'
TO_PATTERN='C:\Animal\'
sed 's/'${FROM_PATTERN//\\/\\\\}'/'${TO_PATTERN//\\/\\\\}'/g' file
```

Use parameter expansion in bash to escape the back slashed parameters.

N.B. The FROM_PATTERN and TO_PATTERN are single quoted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use single quote to assign variables, but if you use double quotes, then you need to escape twice because the back slashes will be interpreted twice: once on assignment, and once in `sed`.

You have to use double quote for variables to expand in sed.

The following code works:

```
FROM_PATTERN="C:\\\\A\\\\quick\\\\brown\\\\fox\\\\"
TO_PATTERN="C:\\\\Animal\\\\"

sed "s/$FROM_PATTERN/$TO_PATTERN/g" input.txt
```